# Cannot open include file - 'gtest.h' - No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, googletest

I am trying to build gtest in Visual Studio, but seem to be having some problems getting the references and includes specified correctly for the project.

**error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gtest/gtest.h': No such file or directory c:\gtest-1.6.0\src\gtest-all.cc**

```
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\GTestBuild.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  gtest-all.cc
1>c:\gtest-1.6.0\src\gtest-all.cc(40): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gtest/gtest.h': No such file or directory
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.61
```

To the Project, I added in the  Project Project Pages > C/C++>Additional Include Directories list references to the following:

```
c:\gtest-1.6.0
c:\gtest-1.6.0\src
c:\gtest-1.6.0\include
c:\gtest-1.6.0\include\gtest
```

but I seem to be missing some other includes or probably did not set this right and would appreciate some help in solving this, and learning how to do this for future as well.

PS.  Switching from

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
// The following lines pull in the real gtest *.cc files.
#include "src/gtest.cc"
#include "src/gtest-death-test.cc"
#include "src/gtest-filepath.cc"
#include "src/gtest-port.cc"
#include "src/gtest-printers.cc"
#include "src/gtest-test-part.cc"
#include "src/gtest-typed-test.cc"
```

To

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

// The following lines pull in the real gtest *.cc files.
#include <src/gtest.cc>
#include <src/gtest-death-test.cc>
#include <src/gtest-filepath.cc>
#include <src/gtest-port.cc>
#include <src/gtest-printers.cc>
#include <src/gtest-test-part.cc>
#include <src/gtest-typed-test.cc>
```

is not a solution. I have tried this and it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the full compilation output to see whether these include directories are being incorporated into the compilation. It should look something like:

```
...
-Ic:\gtest-1.6.0 -Ic:\gtest-1.6.0\src -Ic:\gtest-1.6.0\include -Ic:\gtest-1.6.0\include\gtest
...
```

Have you also *looked* for the file in these directories? Don't forget that as you're including it with a directory, you'll have to look for `gtest.h` in the following directories:

```
c:\gtest-1.6.0\gtest
c:\gtest-1.6.0\src\gtest
c:\gtest-1.6.0\include\gtest
c:\gtest-1.6.0\include\gtest\gtest
```

(Note the `gtest` subdirectory as you using `#include "gtest/gtest.h"`)

Comment: How do I access the full compilation output please? I don't have a listing of the includes in my output window. Also, the gtest subdirectory only exists in the include folder.

Comment: @Kobojunkie: There should be an option in the project options for this. I don't use VS so I can't tell you exactly what it is. Ultimately, you have to find `gtest.h`. If it's in one of the above directories (without the `gtest` postfix) then all you have to do is remove the directory suffix from your include so it looks like `#include "gtest.h"`. On the other hand if it's not in any of these directories then you need to find out where it is. Check out this link http://blog.feabhas.com/2012/03/ also which suggests it might be in `c:\gtest-1.6.0\include` or `c:\gtest-1.6.0\include\gtest`

Comment: The linked helped a great deal

Answer (score 2):

If you look in the Property Pages for the file gtest-all.cc, its Additional Include Directories field should show:

```
..;..\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

if you used the provided msvc\gtest.sln, or else:

```
C:/gtest-1.6.0/include;C:/gtest-1.6.0;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

if you used CMake to create a VS solution.

If the field is empty, then it is not getting the directories you set for the full project, since they are applied via the `%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)` variable.  If this *is* the case, it may be worth getting a fresh download and starting again, since the build is no longer in good shape.

Comment: That is it the field is not empty. I manually added the references myself using system variables. ${GTEST_DIR}
${GTEST_DIR_INCLUDE}. I am able to confirm that they are in there.

Comment: So you're saying then that `C:/gtest-1.6.0/include;C:/gtest-1.6.0` is in the field for both the project *and* gtest-all.cc (two separate Property Pages)?  If that's the case, then the only option left is that C:\gtest-1.6.0\include\gtest\gtest.h is inaccessible.  Can you open C:\gtest-1.6.0\include\gtest\gtest.h OK?